# Windows Store App unable to append text

Tags: windows, string, append, text-files

I am using the following Code to Read all the lines from a textfile into an array and then checking the first 4 characters of of the line and if it equals something writing that line to a different file.

```
        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        String FileName = "APP DataFile.csv";
        int correct = 0;
        var file = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(FileName) as IStorageFile;
        var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            correct += 1;
        String tempf = line.Substring(0, 4);
        pageTitle_Copy.Text = tempf;
            if (tempf == "Ebbs")
            { writetofile("DataFile_SWANSCOMBE.csv", line); }
            else { };
    ____________________________________________________________________________
      private async void writetofile(String FileName, String tempfi)
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        String BodyText = tempfi + Environment.NewLine;            
        StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(sampleFile, BodyText);

    }
```

It seems to work ok but i keep getting the following error

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

BodyText    = "Ebbsfleet Academy,Phase 2,First Floor,GT Classroom,172,726670 - Socket doesn't fit trunking holes apparent please make safe and repair,Ebbsfleet-26-05-2015-11-31-01.jpg\r\n"    string
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists = OpenIfExists Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption
        FileName    = "DataFile_SWANSCOMBE.csv" string
+       sampleFile  = {Windows.Storage.StorageFile} Windows.Storage.StorageFile
+       storageFolder   = {Windows.Storage.StorageFolder}   Windows.Storage.StorageFolder
+       this    = {HCP1.SplitPage1} HCP1.SplitPage1

Problem is when I look at the file it is trying to write to it has already sucessfuly written some of the lines to it Sometimes two line and then crash sometimes 3 lines and sometimes 0 lines

the file is not read only

Any ideas?

Mark

Comment: You don't `await` the call to `writetofile` for one thing.

Comment: Sorry I'm Not that experienced at files do you mean I have to call the method a different way?

Comment: Thanks you So much for pointing me in the right direction I couldn't work out how to call the method so I got rid of it and put the text where I was calling it and it works perfect. does add extra code though as I need to call it 20 times

Comment: Instead of just calling `writetofile(...)` you can do `await writetofile(...)` and it will be fine. By convention, you should consider naming the method `WriteToFileAsync` although that makes no difference to the compiler or runtime. And in theory you should have gotten a warning saying you didn't await the method. Also you need to return `async Task` rather than `async void`